# MyEclipse taking too much time to build workspace

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, myeclipse, jspx

**This is the problem which always comes in a dialog box**

MyEclipse has detected that less than 5% of the 472MB of Tenured Gen (Heap memory) space remains.

It is strongly recommended that you exit and restart MyEclipse with new virtual machine
memory paramters to increase this memory.  Failure to do so can result in data loss.

**sometime this dialog box come with some internal error**

[image]

whenever i try to open java file or jsp file it also take time to open.
Please tell what should i do in such case. Please  help me out.

**Sometime it also shows the following error**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the memory size, as mentioned in the first error message. Memory parameters are at the end of the myeclipse.ini file (in the same folder as the myeclipse.exe file). If you're running the 32 bit version, increase the -Xmx parameter in small increments until you get a running stable environment. For the 64 bit version, you can increase in larger steps.